# Javascript Blob Download

Tags: javascript

Following Problem: this Code isn't working in IE9. And in an actual Chrome Browser it is working but the downloaded file is corrupt (the "corrupted file" part also could happen elsewhere ... any suggestion how to do it in IE9 would be nice ).

```
var file = records[0].data.Files[0].Value.Buffer;
var fileName = records[0].data.Files[0].Value.FileName;
var a = window.document.createElement('a');

a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
a.download = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(a)
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a)
```

Comment: IE9 doesn't support  blobs, blob urls or download attribute on anchors. what is `records[0].data.Files[0].Value.Buffer` suppose to be?

Comment: i would be easy to download the file directly from an api controller. But that would break the architecture pattern. And pattern breaks, only to support, legacy ... maybe some knows a way to get IE9 working

Comment: records[0].data.Files is a standard "multipart/form-data" approach